# What is the purpose of custom events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, custom-event

I am having trouble understanding in what situations you would use custom events.
I mean the ones created by the `CustomEvent` constructor.

I understand the syntax itself, just not why it is useful. It would be nice if somebody could provide an example of real world application of custom events.

Comment: It's a messaging system. Anything you might do with that from within a browser would work. Most answers will probably rely mostly on domain-specific examples (like a transactional accounting app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it ([shameless plug](https://github.com/MeirionHughes/aurelia-resize)) to raise "resize" events on div elements and then use a separate binding framework (aurelia) to listen to those events.

the explicit code example is:

```
var element = this.element; // some element
var erd = erd({ strategy: 'scroll' });

var widthOld = element.offsetWidth;
var heightOld = element.offsetHeight;

this.callback = () => {
  var event = new CustomEvent("resize", {
    detail: {
      width: this.element.offsetWidth,
      height: this.element.offsetHeight,
      widthOld: widthOld,
      heightOld: heightOld
    }
  });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
  widthOld = this.element.offsetWidth;
  heightOld = this.element.offsetHeight;
};

erd.listenTo(this.element, this.callback);
```

where erd is [element-resize-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-resize-detector) that allows you to detect when any div changes shape.